# Not able to see test automation results in Microsoft teams via jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, microsoft-teams, appium-android

I am using jenkins to run the mobile and api automation. I have used office 365 connector to send the automation status in microsoft teams. As per office 365 connector documentation, the jenkins will send test status as well such as total test, passed and failed. But I am not able to see the test results in teams, it only shows Build status. Does anyone knows about it?

Jenkins: 2.204
office 365 connector:   4.12.1
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have cross posted this question to [office-365-connector-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/office-365-connector-plugin/issues/195) repo.